# Subclass AFNetworking JSON Response Serialization to insert JSON response body in to error data in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, afnetworking-2

AFNetworking does not return the JSON response body when it fails (e.g. 400 status code), therefore you must subclass *AFJSONResponseSerializer* and fill in the error object with such. This is the recommended [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2410) and an example is [here](http://blog.gregfiumara.com/archives/239)

Up until Swift 2, I used the following code to achieve such:

```
import Foundation

let JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey : String = "JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey"
let JSONResponseUndefinedAPIFailureReason : String = "UNKNOWN_ERROR"

class JSONResponseSerializerWithData: AFJSONResponseSerializer
{
    override func responseObjectForResponse (response: NSURLResponse, data: NSData, error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer
    <NSError?>) -> AnyObject
    {
       var json : AnyObject  = super.responseObjectForResponse(response, data: data, error: error) as AnyObject

        if (error.memory? != nil)
        {
            var errorValue = error.memory!
            var userInfo = errorValue.userInfo
            if let errorDetail = json["detail"] as? String
            {
                userInfo![JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey] = errorDetail
            }
            else
            {
                userInfo![JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey] = JSONResponseUndefinedAPIFailureReason
            }
            error.memory = NSError(domain: errorValue.domain, code: errorValue.code, userInfo: userInfo)
        }
        return json
    }
}
```

Start with Swift 2, a new type of Error handling was introduced.
The signature of the above function is now:

```
override func responseObjectForResponse(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!) throws -> AnyObject
```

I am having trouble achieving the same as above inside a do-catch statement as it seems the failure does not invoke the catch statement, and thus there is no access to the error object. Further, new ErrorTypes are essentially empty and don't contain

This is what I've tried, but the catch statement is never called:

```
class JSONResponseSerializerWithData: AFJSONResponseSerializer
{
    override func responseObjectForResponse(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!) throws -> AnyObject
    {
        do
        {
            return try super.responseObjectForResponse(response, data: data)
        }
        catch
        {
            let nsError = (error as NSError)
            var userInfo = nsError.userInfo
            if let errorDetail = userInfo["detail"] as? String
            {

                userInfo[JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey] = errorDetail
            }
            else
            {
                userInfo[JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey] = JSONResponseUndefinedAPIFailureReason
            }

            throw NSError(domain: nsError.domain, code: nsError.code, userInfo: userInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried stepping through the AFNetworking2 Library an the body of the response is there, so I could sub-class it in Objective-C rather than Swift, but would prefer doing such if possible.

[image]

Am I handling this incorrectly with a do-catch statement? Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After more digging, I have found that the issue is as described [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2810).

The error is not thrown, only filled, therefore catch is never called. To induce this old behaviour you can add "NS_SWIFT_NOTHROW" to the end of the Objective-C signature in the header file as described [here](https://github.com/christophercotton/AFNetworking/commit/0b09b1afae852cf093249f539b69e11cd6ade8e8)

This will change the signature to:

```
override func responseObjectForResponse(response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSErrorPointer) -> AnyObject?
```

Which can then be used like before.